# paypal different pages - visa/debit payment not create account

Tags: paypal

Hi I have searched for this solution and although others have experienced the same problem I couldn't find a solution that works for my site.

My wordpress site mainly sells registrations/bookings for events and I'm using the s2Memberplugin to process the payments with Paypal. The problem is that when we direct the users/customers to the paypal page to complete the transaction which i want set up with the option of paying via credit/debit card if the user/customer doesn’t have (or doesn’t want to create one) a paypal account. That has been working perfectly except for when users/customers are using a variety of internet browser with various cookie settings so the user/customer get’s directed to a completely different page both in appearance and functionality from the page I want them to see. This incorrect page ‘requires’ users/customers to have or create a paypal account to make the payment, no option to pay via card is available. I tried calling paypal and of course they say it is something wrong with my site.

Over 20 days ago i lodged a support ticket with Paypal MTS (or whatever they are called) and of course no response. I have lodged about 5 more tickets and made about 10 more phone calls and they simply don't care about customers. That is clearly demonstrated when you ask to speak to the complaints section and they say "We don't have a complaints section'

Thanks very much, any assistance is greatly appreciated

---

I haven't been provided with any error codes, unfortunately - i did ask for them but nobody supplied them.

we just discovered that the payflow and IPN settings within my sites plugin were empty but i'm filling them in now but i have two questions:

```
The vendor, is that just my username for my paypal account? (why don't they just use the same terminology - confusing)

My s2Member plugin say's i'll need my IPN url (and then supplies a url, but whn i look at the IPN notification url within my paypal settings it's a totally different link. Should i be changing my paypal IPN url to that which is supplied by my s2Member plugin or am i getting two different url's confused?
```

Thanks for your help again mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Payments Standard this experience is cookie based as you mentioned.  If you want to make sure the full credit card form shows up and allows people to pay with a credit card without creating an account you can use the [Express Checkout API](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf) instead.

In your [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) request you just need to set SOLUTION=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing.

Comment: Thanks very much Andrew, I really appreciate your assistance. Just to clarify, when you say that I need to set my setexpresscheckout request to 'SOLUTION=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing' are you saying that i change that within my paypal account settings or are you meaning that I have to do that somwhere on my website? Sorry to ask what may be a really dumb question but i can't afford to make any mistakes with this. Thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: It would be in your code generating the API requests.  If you're just using standard button code from PayPal you won't have that option.  You'd have to switch to the actual Express Checkout API.

Comment: Ok so we've modified the site so it will take them to a page that always seems to allow the user to choose to pay with a credit card, but now people are having their cards denied. No matter how many different cards they try, they are always denied. What are we supposed to do now mate? This PayPal issue is driving me nuts, you would think that using PayPal would be the simplest and most reliable option but it's far from it. Please help.

Comment: I would need to know error codes that you're getting back to help you with that.